# iconRef without fsspec

Tags: macos, macos-carbon, deprecated, core-services

I am trying to programatically add a startup item with LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL (the [recommended](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/CustomLogin.html) method in 10.5 going forward)

The call requests, but does not require an icon for the item. the icon is supplied by iconRef.

iconRef can be created by using an FSSpec to the icon file. My understanding is that FS Spec is deprecated in 10.4 going forwards.

Is there a way to get the apps .icns in iconRef without resorting to FSSpec or do I just have to use NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding is that FS Spec is deprecated in 10.4 going forwards.

Longer than that.

> Is there a way to get the apps .icns in iconRef without resorting to FSSpec or do I just have to use NULL?

Use [the `RegisterIconRefFromFSRef` function](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/reference/IconServices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/RegisterIconRefFromFSRef).

Passing `NULL` will add the item with no icon; IIRC, it'll have the document icon when the user looks at their login items list in System Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

The IconsCore.h file says to use `GetIconRefFromFileInfo`:

```
extern OSStatus 
GetIconRefFromFileInfo(
  const FSRef *            inRef,
  UniCharCount             inFileNameLength,
  const UniChar *          inFileName,             /* can be NULL */
  FSCatalogInfoBitmap      inWhichInfo,
  const FSCatalogInfo *    inCatalogInfo,          /* can be NULL */
  IconServicesUsageFlags   inUsageFlags,
  IconRef *                outIconRef,
  SInt16 *                 outLabel)               /* can be NULL */
```

The comments on the deprecated function `GetIconRefFromFile` say you should use this. You can turn your `CFURL` into the `FSRef` using `CFURLGetFSRef`. Hope that helps.

Comment: This function gets the icon *of* an item. Passed a .icns file, it will probably give you Preview's icon for a .icns document. If you want to use the icon *in* the icon file, the function for that is RegisterIconRefFromFSRef.

Comment: Hey @PeterHosey, how do you get an icon reference using `RegisterIconRefFromFSRef`. I don't get the creator and icontype codes.

Comment: @ElDeveloper: You should ask a separate question about that.